# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ./bless)

Tags: gcc

I have installed the software bless on Ubuntu 12.04 without errors, but when I run the bless, I got the following errors.
I have no idea how to solve this problem though I have searched it on google for a long time.
Thank you very for any advices and idea.

```
$ ./bless
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ./bless)
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./bless)
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./bless)

$ ldd ./bless 
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ./bless)
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./bless)
./bless: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./bless)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd3c3d4000)
        libmpicxx.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libmpicxx.so.12 (0x00007f7eb6f0b000)
        libmpi.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007f7eb6a9d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7eb679d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7eb64a1000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f7eb6293000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7eb607d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7eb5e60000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7eb5aa2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7eb589a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7eb712d000)
```